# User-defined type not defined VBA

Tags: vba

There is compile error

> 'user-defined type not defined'

I get in VB6 when I was tried to compile this code. Can anybody tell me what I need to do to solve this error? Following is the line for which I got the error:
Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Set cnnConnection = New ADODB.connection

    cnnConnection.Open ("Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _"data Source=180.125.20.96;" & _"Initial Catalog=path_test; " & _"User Id=sa;Password=Psword4886")
    rstRecordset.Open "Select * from REM_M_Pojhd where PRJCDE =@PRJCDE", cnnConnection, _adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

    Dim command As New SqlCommand("Select * from REM_M_Prjhdrimg where PRJCD =@PRJCD", connection)
    command.Parameters.Add("@PRJCD", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)

    adapter.Fill (table)

    If table.Rows.Count() <= 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show ("No Image For This Id")
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = table.Rows(0)(0).ToString()
        TextBox2.Text = table.Rows(0)(1).ToString()
        TextBox3.Text = table.Rows(0)(2).ToString()
        Dim img() As Byte
        img = table.Rows(0)(3)
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(img)
        Image1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm not much a knowledgeable programmer, I'm still just a student, do explain it in a little bit detailed statements.
thanks!

Comment: which line gives you the error?

Comment: So there is a huge difference between VBA and VB6! Please make sure which one you are using by [edit]ing your question and tags.

Comment: I do hope that the datasource, ID and password in your connection string are not sensible informations...

Comment: Hi Syntax code is correct . and this code is working running properly in windows application,but we need to run this code in VBA excel 2010 macro enable. also i dont have that much knowledge of VBA please help me out.

Comment: So the code **IS** actually VBA???  (It doesn't really look like it is but, if it actually is, please edit the tags and question to get rid of the mention of VB6.)

Answer (score 1):

I am presuming there is supposed to be a gap between the first 3 lines of your code (VBA/VB6) and the remainder which is VB.Net.

In VBA `Set cnnConnection = New ADODB.connection` is failing with *user-defined type not defined* because you have not added a reference to *Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library 2.x* causing `ADODB.connection` to be unknown at compile time.